# Multiple errors on math equation

Tags: math-mode, errors, amssymb, missing

Being relatively new to Latex, I try to implement the following expression:

[image]

To do so, I used the following code (while using the `amssymb` package):

```
\( 
\textbf{Y} = (\textbf{Y\textsubscript{\emph{v}}})\textsubscript{\emph{v} \in \emph{V}}
\)
```

This shows the formula correctly, but the text that comes after this is still writter in subscript as well. Furthermore, this approach results in multiple errors:

```
 - Missing $ inserted
 - Extra }, or forgotten $
 - Latex error: something is wrong -- perhaps a missing \item 
 - Latex error: something is wrong -- perhaps a missing \item 
 - Missing $ inserted
 - Missing } inserted
```

Clearly, the structure of my formula is not correct. However, I don't see what it is.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here and what I can do resolve it?

Comment: You want simply `\((\mathbf{Y}_{v})_{v \in V}\)`. I suggest you give a look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/82917)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\( % start inline math mode
\mathbf{Y} = (\mathbf{Y}_{v})_{v\in V} 
\) % end inline math mode
\end{document}
```

Do note that when TeX is in (inline or display) math mode, (a) the `_` ("underscore") character should be used to initiate subscript material, (b) `\mathbf` rather than `\textbf` should be used, and (c) TeX typesets letters of the Latin alphabet in (math) italics by default.

For sure, don't use the text-mode commands such as `\emph` and `\textsubscript` while in math mode.

[image]